# Differentiation of a time derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I apologise if this question seems basic but this is the first time I came across such differentiation -

Given a function

$\dot{x_t} = a_tx_t + by_t - z_t$.                                 ... (1)

Where, both $y_t$ and $z_t$ are not a function of $x_t$.

I need to diffentiate $\dot{x_t}$ with respect to $x_{t+1}$.

I tried integrating expression for $\dot{x_t}$ and then differentiating but that approach seems too cumbersome. Is there any easier way of doing it?

Context:
Maximize function - U($z_t$) subject to budget constraint given in (1)....by finding optimal level of $x_{t+1}$

In this problem, $z_t$ is consumption. I want to choose optimal level of capital that I should invest, a form of saving, that will maximize my Utility function.

Comment: Could you give a little more context on why this derivative is necessary? Intuitively it makes little sense, one would rather expect the derivative of $x_{t+1}$ for $x_t$.

Comment: @LutzL Thank you for your response. I have edited my question and added the context. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ depends on some constant $C$, and $y$ and $z$ do not, then by the commutativity of partial derivatives (assuming that the conditions are satisfied)
$\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$
$$
\pd{}{t}\left(\pd{x_t}{C}\right)=\pd{}{C}\pd{x_t}{t}=a\left(\pd{x_t}{C}\right)
$$
This is also true if $C$ is the value of $x_{t+1}$.

Comment: Thank you. I recently made a correction to my question. Will this hold true if we have a_t instead of just a? Also, can you explain from where does a come from?